# Typo3 Form Elements "Login Form" Not Visible

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I have added a Default Login form of Typo3 Form Elements in a page. But it is not visible.

- I'm using Typo3 8.7.x.
- I have not added any CSS or JS.

What may the problem? is there a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new form framework of TYPO3 8 can be used as frontend login form but this will not work out of the box. Instead, install the core extension "felogin". Don't forget to add the static TypoScript template of this extension to your TypoScript.

Furthermore, there is a documentation available: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/felogin/

Answer (score 1):

In New TYPO3 8.7 , it's replaced with Form extension (it's new ExtBase extension launch)
Please search form Form in your extension manager , you will find Form extension.

Checkout this screenshot:

[image]

If you still want to use the old form , please install this extension on your 8.7 version: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/form_legacy/

Thanks

I hope it helps !!!

Comment: i have added a form but i'm getting a error like this - _Sorry, the requested view was not found_

`The technical reason is: No template was found. View could not be resolved for action "render" in class "TYPO3\CMS\Form\Controller\FormFrontendController"`

Comment: do you include template from the root template ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that. I added it. Now it is working thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry , Another doubt is, How can i use this to for the website user login. i'm using this for website user login.